# No module named 'client.api'

Tags: jupyter

When I try to set up an jupyter notebook environment for the ucb data100 course.(I am not a ucb student,so I have to set up environment locally.)
Firstly,there is no module named "client" and i download a client package "nbclient". It goes on. But then the error "No module named 'client.api'" appears. And i try as before. I search some packages for client.api and download one package named "api-client". It can't work. Then I find all matching packages in PYPI. With these packages's descriptions,I can't find others matched it.

How can I fix it and run sucessfully?